# How to set a timeout for a popup and close if user clicks elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a popup that appears when I click a button, but to make it disappear I have to click again. Is there a way to set a timer and make it disappear?

Function:

```
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Style:

```
.popuptext {
  display: none;
}
.popuptext.show {
  display: block;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

I need the popup to close after 10 seconds OR when the user clicks somewhere else.

I edited the code to below and it does close after 10 seconds, how to achieve the second part (close when user clicks somewhere else):

```
function myFunction() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
if(popup.classList.contains("show"))
    setTimeout(() => popup.classList.remove("show"), 10000)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something like `body.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.matches('#myPopup, #myPopup *') || hidePopup())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to:

- Define a function, `hide()` that hides the popup.
- Add an `mousedown` event listener to the whole `document` that invokes `hide`

  - Within `hide`, ensure that the click event's `target` is not contained in the popup.
- Set up the timeout to call `hide`
- **Important**: Have `hide` clear the created timeout and remove the listener that was added.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.add('show')
  
  let timeout;
  
  function hide(e) {
    if (popup.contains(e.target)) return;

    popup.classList.remove("show");
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', hide);
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', hide)
  timeout = setTimeout(hide, 10000)
}
```

```css
.popuptext {
  display: none;
}

.popuptext.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this will close popup even when user click on the popup

Answer (score 1):

check with click event occurred not on `popup`

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.popup').length){

        // you clicked outside of popup, write your logic to close popup
        var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        if(popup.classList.contains("show")){
          popup.classList.remove("show")
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm missing in the other answers is that what you're looking for is called [Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).

By attaching a click event to your document, you can use Javascript to see what exactly has been clicked:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  // What has been clicked?
  const elementClicked = e.target.id;
});
```

Now you can work with it:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  // What has been clicked?
  const elementClicked = e.target.id;

  if(elementClicked == 'your_button')
  {
    // Your button is clicked. Popup your modal for the user and set the timer.
  }
  else
  {
    // Something else was clicked. Close the popup IF it exists. Disable the timer.
  }

});
```

You see the power of event delegation? You can now catch any click, regardless of what it is, and do something with it, depending on what it is.

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this in two different ways

**First**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div  id="flyout-example">
      <h5 >This could be a flyout;</h5>
      <div id="flyout-debug"></div>
      <div>
        <button class="button button-outline" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button class="button" type="button">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        const flyoutEl = document.getElementById("flyout-example");
        let targetEl = evt.target; // clicked element      
        do {
          if(targetEl == flyoutEl) {
            // This is a click inside, does nothing, just return.
            document.getElementById("flyout-debug").textContent = "Clicked inside!";
            return;
          }
          // Go up the DOM
          targetEl = targetEl.parentNode;
        } while (targetEl);
        // This is a click outside.      
        document.getElementById("flyout-debug").textContent = "Clicked outside!";
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Second**

```
$(window).click(function () { //Hide the menus if visible });
```

if popup is getting close when clicking on it use `stopPropogation`

```
$('#menucontainer').click(function (event) {event.stopPropagation();});
```